# SASS maps with mixins

Tags: css, sass

I would like to get some help trying to fill the custom mixin with data comming from $themes map

```
// THEMES
$themes: (
  theme1: (
    main-color: $theme1-main-color,
    second-color: $theme1-second-color,
    main-font: $theme1-main-font,
    size-font: $theme1-font-size
  ),
  theme2: (
    main-color: $theme2-main-color,
    second-color: $theme2-second-color,
    main-font: $theme2-main-font,
    size-font: $theme2-font-size
  )
);

@mixin custom-font($family: false, $size: false, $weight: false, $colour: false, $lh: false) {
  @if $family { font-family: $family; }
  @if $size { font-size: $size; }
  @if $colour { color: $colour; }
  @if $weight { font-weight: $weight; }
  @if $lh { line-height: $lh; }
}
// MAP

@each $name, $teste in $themes {
  .theme-#{$name} {
    .background { background: main-color($name); }
    .link { color: second-color($name); }
    h1{@include custom-font((main-font($name)),(size-font($name)))}
  }
}
```

Code:

[Play with this gist on SassMeister.](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/f24608d3e83ed493431ecc653d9b78e3)